# Need to find average value across multi-level nested SQL query in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

This one's a bit of a mess, and there's probably some far superior way of doing this but we just need the information for some reports we're working on.

So, we have a bunch of projects; each project has a bunch of tasks and each task has a document type ID associated with it.  A project can belong to one or more workgroups.

We want to analyze projects that have at least one task of doc type x, and then see how many workgroups it has.  I can do that with:

```
   select distinct T.PROJECTID,
      (select COUNT(*) from TPM_PROJECTWORKGROUPS where PROJECTID=T.PROJECTID) as NumWorkgroups
   from TPM_TASK T
   where T.DOCUMENTTYPEID=17
```

Now, we want to see the average number of workgroups across these projects.  So I can do:

```
select AVG(NumWorkgroups) FROM (
   select distinct T.PROJECTID,
      (select COUNT(*) from TPM_PROJECTWORKGROUPS where PROJECTID=T.PROJECTID) as NumWorkgroups
   from TPM_TASK T
   where T.DOCUMENTTYPEID=17
)
```

However, we want to run this same query across all the document types (there's about 200 of them).  I can't find a way to do this without copying and pasting the query 200 times.  I've tried:

```
select DOCUMENTTYPEID, 
    (select AVG(NumWorkgroups) FROM (
       select distinct T.PROJECTID,
          (select COUNT(*) from TPM_PROJECTWORKGROUPS where PROJECTID=T.PROJECTID) as NumWorkgroups
       from TPM_TASK T
       where T.DOCUMENTTYPEID=DT.DOCUMENTTYPEID
    ))
from TPM_DOCUMENTTYPE DT
```

However, I get the error:

```
ORA-00904: "TPM_DOCUMENTTYPE"."DOCUMENTTYPEID": invalid identifier
```

I believe because DT is out of scope more than one level down in a nested query.  Is there a better way to do this query?

**Update for Justin:**

Here's a sample schema:

```
create table Test_Projects (
  id   number primary key
)

create table Test_Tasks (
  id   number primary key,
  project number,
  doctype number
)

create table Test_Workgroups (
  id   number primary key,
  workgroup number,
  project number
)
```

With some sample data:

```
insert into Test_Projects VALUES (1) --Create projects 1 and 2
insert into Test_Projects VALUES (2)
insert into Test_Tasks VALUES (1, 1, 5) --Project 1 has two tasks, doc types 5 and 6
insert into Test_Tasks VALUES (2, 1, 6)
insert into Test_Tasks VALUES (3, 2, 6) --Project 2 has one task, doc type 6
insert into Test_Workgroups VALUES (1, 1, 1) --Project 1 belongs to workgroups 1 and 2
insert into Test_Workgroups VALUES (2, 2, 1)
insert into Test_Workgroups VALUES (3, 2, 2) --Project 2 belongs to workgroup 2
```

We need to know the average number of workgroups that a project with a task of type x belongs to.

For example, doc type 5 has only project 1 which has 2 workgroups, so the average is 2.  Doc type 6 has 2 projects (1 and 2) - 1 has 2 workgroups and 2 has one workgroup - so the average is 1.5.

We need to list all doc types and the average number of workgroups in each.

I'd expect this query to return:

```
DOCTYPE     AverageWorkgroups
-------     -----------------
5           2
6           1.5
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the sample data.  That makes it much clearer.

I believe this does what you want (I'm including the calculations for the number of projects and the number of workgroups in the output as well just because that made my testing easier)

```
SQL> ed
Wrote file afiedt.buf

  1  select t.doctype,
  2         count(distinct p.id) numProjects,
  3         count(*) numWorkgroups,
  4         count(*)/ count( distinct p.id) avgNumWorkgroups
  5    from test_projects p,
  6         test_tasks    t,
  7         test_workgroups w
  8   where p.id = t.project
  9     and p.id = w.project
 10*  group by t.doctype
SQL> /

   DOCTYPE NUMPROJECTS NUMWORKGROUPS AVGNUMWORKGROUPS
---------- ----------- ------------- ----------------
         6           2             3              1.5
         5           1             2                2
```

Comment: Hmm this seems to be giving me different results.  For doc id 17, my query gives me an average of 23 and yours (for row 17) has an average of 65.  So something is not quite working.  I'll keep working on it.

Comment: @MikeChristensen - That's why posting the DML to create some sample data along with the expected results is helpful.  That way, we can test our queries locally and we're not making assumptions about what your data looks like.

Comment: Ok I added some sample data.  Sorry, this query is near impossible to really explain and our actual tables are way too complicated to post here :) (Nor would my employer appreciate me posting their DB schema)..

Comment: @MikeChristensen - OK.  Updated my answer using the sample data you provided.

Comment: Yea I think the numWorkgroups value is not correct.  I expect to be able to do `select count(*) from TPM_PROJECTWORKGROUPS where PROJECTID in (select distinct projectid from TPM_TASK where DOCUMENTTYPEID=1)` and see the same value for that doc type.  Hmmm..

Comment: @MikeChristensen - Is the numWorkgroups value not correct for the sample data you posted?  Or is there some additional data condition that the query I posted doesn't handle?  Can you post additional sample data that demonstrates that case?

Comment: There must be additional data conditions that I'm not taking into account.  I don't mean to usurp all your time on this, I'll figure it out from here.